# Arrange value in array according another array

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, task

I have an array with points (e.g. [20, 6, 5, 15, 6, 3, 3, 11, 9, 3]) and an empty array.
It needs to populate an empty array to the place according to points in the first array.

For example:
the largest value of points is 20, so emptyArray[0] = 1, the next largest value is 15, so emptyArray[3] = 2 and so on.

Second condition:
If I have the same value, it must have the same number of places.
So for the array of points [20, 6, 5, 15, 6, 3, 3, 11, 9, 3] result array of place will look next [1, 5, 6, 2, 5, 7, 7, 3, 4, 7].

Please help!

Comment: How is this different from your previous question ?

Comment: @Tenfour04 In previous question I didn't mention about second condition. These are different tasks, but you are right, they are similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
fun main() {
    val points = listOf(20, 6, 5, 15, 6, 3, 3, 11, 9, 3)
    val places = populatePlaces(points)
    println(places) // Output: [1, 5, 6, 2, 5, 7, 7, 3, 4, 7]
}

fun populatePlaces(points: List<Int>): List<Int> {
    val indexedPoints = points.mapIndexed { index, value -> Pair(index, value) }
    val sortedPoints = indexedPoints.sortedWith(compareByDescending<Pair<Int, Int>> { it.second }.thenBy { it.first })

    val places = MutableList(points.size) { 0 }
    var place = 1

    for (i in sortedPoints.indices) {
        val index = sortedPoints[i].first
        if (i > 0 && sortedPoints[i].second != sortedPoints[i - 1].second) {
            place++
        }
        places[index] = place
    }

    return places
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of Question #75838470?

Comment: @RandomLonelyDev No, last question doesn't have second condition about same values.